# I'm new to using MYSQL and I'm having trouble locating my syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql

I keep getting a syntax error, but I'm new to SQL and I am having trouble locating the error. I have reviewed multiple articles with no luck in solving my problem

```sql
CREATE TABLE 'stock_prices' (
'price_date' DATE NOT NULL,    
'minute_time' DATETIME NOT NULL,
'ticker' VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
'open_price' DECIMAL(15,6) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
'high_price' DECIMAL(15,6) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
'low_price' DECIMAL(15,6) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
'close_price' DECIMAL(15,6) NULL DEFAULT NULL,                                  
'total_volume' BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,                                             
'total_quantity' INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,                                     
'total_trade_count' INT(11) NOT NULL,                                           
PRIMARY KEY ('ticker'))ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''stock_data' ( 'price_date' DATE NOT NULL,
'minute_time' DATETIME NOT NULL,
'tic' at line 1
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql

Comment: Getting the quotes wrong is a simple typo, in my opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the quotes:

```
CREATE TABLE stock_prices ( `price_date` DATE NOT NULL, 
  `minute_time` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `ticker` VARCHAR(20), 
  `open_price` DECIMAL(15,6) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `high_price` DECIMAL(15,6) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `low_price` DECIMAL(15,6) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `close_price` DECIMAL(15,6) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `total_volume` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
  `total_quantity` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `total_trade_count` INT(11) NOT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (`ticker`)) 
ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Even better, you can just omit the quotes.